# Laravel: Resource deadlock avoided

Tags: php, laravel, docker

Just coming back to a project I built with Laravel and Sail (Docker) and I'm encountering an error I've never seen before when running my tests (`sail artisan test`):

`PHP Notice:  require_once(): Read of 675 bytes failed with errno=35 Resource deadlock avoided in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 149`

What does this mean and what could be causing it?

I've tried clearing cache, dumping composer autoload, and restarting the server several times. Why is a "resource deadlock" (sounds like another process is using the file?) and what could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

This was a stupid gotcha. The project was stored in a Dropbox folder that had "helpfully" decided to make certain files "online-only" (ie. delete them from my HD). I'll leave this here incase anyone else finds themselves in a situation where a project suddenly stops working.

Yet another reason to despise Dropbox ([see also](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-ideas/Add-dropboxignore-directory-to-exclude-folders-without-using/idi-p/5926)).